# how to access to property in view(django)

Tags: django, properties

I'm beginner and I need some solution

First, I have Racket and Detail class.

```
class Racket(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class RacketDetail(models.Model):
   racket = models.OneToOneField(Racket, related_name='detail', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   adminReview = models.TextField()
   adminPower = models.FloatField(default=0)
   adminSpin = models.FloatField(default=0)
   adminManeuverability = models.FloatField(default=0)
   adminStability = models.FloatField(default=0)
   adminComfort = models.FloatField(default=0)

   @property
   def adminAvgScore(self):
       scoreAvg = (
                       self.adminPower +
                       self.adminSpin +
                       self.adminManeuverability +
                       self.adminStability +
                       self.adminComfort
               ) / 5
       return round(scoreAvg, 2)
```

Second, I want to rander list using the @property(adminAvgScore), so I made view like this.

```
def racketMain(request: HttpRequest):
   getRacket = Racket.objects.all().order_by('detail__adminAvgScore')
   return render(request, "racket/racketMain.html", {'racketItems': getRacket, })
```

Unfortunally when I use 'RacketDetail' class's column I can access all column except 'adminAvgScore' using by "order_by('detail__".

If I use like "order_by('detail__adminAvgScore')" then Django show to me error "Unsupported lookup 'adminAvgScore' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted."

How can I solve it? Or should I think in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use property with Query as Property is Function. You can use annotate and aggregate combination to get the result as your property function but inside a query.Something like this will do the trick.

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, FloatField, Avg
Model.objects.filter(...)\
    .values('id')\
    .annotate(subtotal=Sum(...math here..., output_field=FloatField()))\
    .aggregate(total=Avg(F('subtotal')))
```